# Automatically background interactive process using job control

Tags: shell, expect, jobs

I have a command line program that receives interactive input.

- I want to have the program backgrounded after it has read the input.
- After it has read the input, it execs another program.  I want to be able to control that program using shell job control.
- I am lazy, so I don't want to type `C-Z` and `bg` to achieve that.

I am in control of that program (I wrote it and can change it), and it 'knows' when it should be backgrounded.

I'm sure this is achievable (for example, I guess an `expect` script could start my program, which could then signal its parent (expect) when it's ready to be backgrounded.

What is the best (simplest, easiest, best-behaving) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following (Assuming bash)?

```
# Get necessary input
exec "/usr/bin/bash" ./AnotherScript.sh
```

Comment: Ha, I was already execing in a shell wrapper, but that works if I add a `&` (edited answer to say that)!  So simple, I didn't know it could be used with `exec` :-)  My script currently is python called from the shell wrapper, but I can change it to just pass the command to launch back to the wrapper script.

Comment: Did not realize you'd like to have the second process backgrounded - in this case yes - adding`&` should do the trick.